# Proposed removal of minor tags: set, rotate, interactivity, conditioned, image-filtering

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

[set](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/set) presently has 13 questions.  Reviewing them it seems about half of them should have been marked with [assignment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assignment), [variable-definitions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/variable-definitions), or perhaps [function-construction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function-construction), and the rest likely mean it in the mathematical sense or simply [list-manipulation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list-manipulation).  There is also [sets](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sets) which appears to be used more consistently.  I propose eliminating [set](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/set).

[rotate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rotate) presently has 5 questions.  There already exists [rotation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rotation) with 26 questions.  I propose making [rotate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rotate) synonym.

[interactivity](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interactivity) presently has 4 questions.  There already exists [interactive](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interactive) with 52 questions. I propose making a synonym.

[conditioned](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditioned) presently has 20 questions.  It seems mostly to be used where [conditional](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditional) (87 questions) would apply.  I propose making it synonymous.  If there is need for a different meaning a more qualified tag name should be used.

[image-filtering](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-filtering) presently has 21 questions.  I question its distinction from [image-processing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing) (629 question) and propose making it synonymous.  Further there exists [filtering](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filtering) if extra specificity is justified.

**Please comment or answer if you disagree with any of these proposals.  Include your reasoning, and any counter-proposals if such apply.  I shall take silence as tacit acquiescence and proceed with the changes.**

Comment: I don't disagree with any of them.

Comment: I, too, refuse to acquiesce silently, I fully support all the above proposals.